# How to do OpenGL 3 programming on OS X with a GeForce 9400

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-3

I have a MacBook Pro with a GeForce 9400 graphics card. Wikipedia said this card supports OpenGL 3.

But the header and library shipped with OS X 10.6 seems to be OpenGL 2 only (I checked the files in `/usr/X11/include/`).

I need to do some OpenGL 3 programming. Can I do it with my current hardware and OS? What do I need to get and install?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I don't think you can yet, [as detailed here](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/mac.htm).

I believe Lion will upgrade OpenGL to 3.2 for OS X though (which is still short of the more useful 3.3 unfortunately).

***NB:*** I do not own a Mac, this is purely from trying to learn modern OpenGL on the windows side and digging around to understand how portable it would be.

Edit: [this thread](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=269933#Post269933) on the official OpenGL forums has more detail. Although (see comments below this answer) it may not be completely clear why vendors cannot provide OpenGL 3+ compliant drivers, it seems pretty clear that there is no way to use fully OpenGL 3.3 compliant code and shaders in OS X. Some workarounds are provided in that thread however, as well as in my first link.

Comment: You mean the reply that says "I don't know enough about Mac OpenGL implementations, but I would hope that they can expose extensions."?  Clearly a solid expert opinion to base your answer on.

Comment: Good point ! That poster does usually have precise and informed opinions on OpenGL though, and the other posters tend to confirm what I was trying to point out : there is no provision in OS X for a mechanism similar to installable client drivers under Windows. Well, either that or absolutely no one on the official forums has realized they can use OpenGL 3+ on OS X just like they do on other platforms, which seems unlikely ;)

Comment: What I got from that thread is that there are ICDs, and the vendors have included a bunch of extensions representing about 65% of OpenGL 3 as of 2009, and nearer 95% by now.  But that the vendors can't implement new core functions without Apple's say-so, not because there's no mechanism (ICD) for doing so, but because Apple asked them not to.

Comment: Replying to both of your comments here for clarity :)
You're right, it's not clearly stated that the limitation is a technical one. I couldn't find a precise explanation of the driver model for OpenGL under OS X and made the assumption that vendors would provide OpenGL 3 compliance if they could; perhaps they technically can and are simply bowing to 'political' pressure from Apple.
The end result is the same though : some OpenGL 3+ functionality is available via extensions but pure 3.3 core profile OpenGL will not work on OS X, most notably because #version 330 GLSL will not compile.

Comment: Edited my post to try to include your corrections to my assumptions ! Thanks for pointing them out :)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to check OpenGL support on the various OSX and Mac combinations is:
http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/

See the "Core" subpage for 10.7+

OpenGL 3.2 with GLSL 1.5 on 10.7.2 isn't too bad.

Comment: "Isn't too bad" considering the 2.0 with 1.2 we are stuck with on slightly "older" Macs.

Comment: So it looks like OpenGL 3.2 is supported in Lion, but how do we enable it?  `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` tells me 1.2 still (on a Macbook Pro / Radeon HD 6490M).

Comment: When creating the PixelFormat ensure that you request kCGLOGLPVersion_3_2_Core ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your current hardware can support OpenGL 3, but not the OS. Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) should support OpenGL 3, which is a solution only if you can wait many months.

Your only option right now is to switch to a different OS such as Windows or Linux.  You'll have to boot from this other operating system, because the virtual machine systems present a virtual video card to the guest operating systems, and none have OpenGL 3 compatible virtual video cards.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: This information is based on taking Windows OpenGL and replacing wgl with glX.  But I did verify that the corresponding extensions exist in GLX land)

You won't find OpenGL 3 support in any header files.  Rather you need the [GLX_ARB_create_context extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt).

The other answers are probably correct about missing support in OSX, but even when support comes, you'll have to use `glXGetProcAddress` and load the extension.  (Can't video card manufacturers add support for these extensions through their driver?  Why does it require "OS support"?)

Comment: See my edit to my answer for why it requires support by Apple : basically, there is no ICD mechanism where the GPU vendor can expose additional features on their own.

Comment: @Bethor: Where do you get this idea that there's no extension mechanism?  Most of the thread you linked is discussing extensions, and the difference between EXT (which Macs support) and ARB extensions (which developers want).  If Apple is throwing its weight around and telling GPU vendors not to include new OpenGL versions in their drivers, that's one thing, but it's not a technical limitation.

Comment: The problem is, how MacOS X implements OpenGL. It's a really stupid method: The OpenGL framework carries parts of the graphics driver. You cannot download a new graphics driver for MacOS X, you get them through OS updates. Part of the reason why Apple does it that way is, that Quartz Extreme is built upon OpenGL and so OpenGL is an integral part of the operating systems graphics subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OpenGL developer here. On Windows 7 only OpenGL 1.4 is officially supported, but everyone gets around this limitation by querying which functions are available at run-time.

On OSX I expect you can do the same thing. The easiest way to do this is with The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLEW/

Comment: Edited my answer with a link explaining why it's not that simple !